# what does the ! mean in this expression: ${!mylist[@]}

Tags: shell, for-loop

I'm trying to understand a shell script written by a previous group member. there is this for loop. I can understand it's looping through a list `${!mylist[@]}` but I've only seen `${mylist[@]}` before, not `${!mylist[@]}`.

What does the exclamation mark do here?

```
for i in ${!mylist[@]};
do
        echo ${mylist[i]}
        ....
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${!mylist[@]}` returns the *keys* (or *indices*) to an an array.  This differs from `${mylist[@]}` which returns the *values* in the array.

As an example, let's consider this array:

```
$ arr=(abc def ghi)
```

In order to get its keys (or *indices* in this case):

```
$ echo "${!arr[@]}"
0 1 2
```

In order to get its values:

```
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
abc def ghi
```

From `man bash`:

> It  is  possible  to  obtain  the keys (indices) of an array as well
>   as the values.  ${!name[@]} and ${!name[*]} expand to the indices
>   assigned in array variable name.  The treatment when in double quotes
>   is similar to the expansion of the special parameters @ and * within
>   double quotes.

#### Example using associative arrays

To show that the same applies to associative arrays:

```
$ declare -A Arr=([a]=one [b]=two)
$ echo "${!Arr[@]}"
a b
$ echo "${Arr[@]}"
one two
```

Comment: That was for *indexed* arrays in bash, you were probably thinking about *associative* arrays (`key => value` pairs) in bash (which thankfully takes a similar approach)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Answer updated to use the word `indices` also.  I used a parens notation similar to the way that `man bash` phrases it.